# Can nfa consume more than one letter at a time

Tags: automata, finite-automata

If I have a NFA/DFA and I expect inputs of 00, 01, 10, 11 can I read input in groups of 2 binary digits at a time.

like the example shown

[image]

Comment: Consult your definition of NFA.

Comment: Not sure what I'm looking for in that sorry

Comment: Can you copy the definition?

Comment: Do you know how to convert an NFA diagram to an NFA as per the formal definition?

Comment: A NFA with  transitions is defined as the 5 tuple
,Σ,,0,where ,Σ,0and are defined in
the canonical way and :×Σ→

Comment: Now, in what way does a diagram describe a 5-tuple?

Comment: Im trying to build I NFA to recognise simultaneous input from 2 input sources, I thought I can set the Σ = {00,01,10,11} union Epsilon Q to be the states F to be the accept states and q0  = S

Comment: In that case, each of 00,01,10,11 is a single letter. You're not consuming more than one letter at a time.

Comment: Thank you so much, so this approach is valid excluding the actual diagram? :)

Comment: There's nothing wrong about the actual diagram. You can replace 00,01,10,11 with names of presidents if you wish, as long as you explain that each of them is just one symbol of the alphabet.

Comment: Do I need an epsilion transition between the concatenation states i.e. n1_c to n1_e?

Comment: How would I know? Only *you* know what your automaton is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as long as your alphabet is defined as a set of different couples of binary digits